# Elasticsearch - Nest - Mapping - Multi target alias or Specifying just 1 multifield subfield to use per document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, nest

We have an application that we are wanting to migrate from solr to elasticsearch. I'm struggling to find the proper way of doing the following (we have 10 fields like this).

We have a text field that is to be indexed and searched using certain analyzers depending on the language. But need to be searched on using the same name. So in Solr we are able to have a "title_fr" and "title_en" fields and have an alias setup that will return/search both when we search the "title" field but at any point in time we only have 1 of those fields populated per document and so this works.

Now I know in elasticsearch an alias can only have 1 target, so I started looking into multi-fields. But the problem with multi fields that I can see is that it stores and creates and index for each sub fields in it. So if I had a multi field called title and then a sub field called title.en and one called title.fr, if I add to index a title, it will add to both title.en and title.fr using the analyzers specified. This becomes a problem because searching in title will trigger the search analyzer for both and return potential false positives in the opposite language. Not to mention it also doubles our index size.

Other options I've seen is to create an index per language and create a cross index alias.

I am using C# Nest to do this work too if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have title_fr and title_en as separate field

Mappings:

```
"mappings":{
    "properties":{
        "title_fr":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":<your_analyzer>                                
        },
        "title_en":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":<your_analyzer>                                
        }
    }
}
```

You can also have these set up as objects or nested type

```
"title":{
    type:"object",
    "properties":{
        "title_fr":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"your_analyzer"
        },
        "title_en":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"your_analyzer"
        }
    }
}
```

There are many options available in elasticsearch to query a text on multiple fields
ex.
You can use [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query":    "<text>",
            "fields": [ "title_fr", "title_en" ]  --> or title.title_fr,title.title_en 
        }
    }
}
```

[Query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "<text>",
            "fields"  : [ "title_fr", "title_en" ]  --> or title.title_fr,title.title_en 
        }
    }
}
```